# How to identify string in htm.getelementbyid("mystring") using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get data from a different website using the vba code bellow, but I don't know how to identify the string inside the parenthesis in this statement "With htm.getelementbyid("comps-results"). How do I get the string in the parenthesis from, for example, [this](https://www.google.com/finance#stockscreener) website

I would appreciate very much if someone could help me on this matter.

Thank you in advance.

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim htm As Object

    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/67083361_zpid/", False
        .send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With

    With htm.getelementbyid("comps-results")
        For x = 0 To .Rows.Length - 1
            For y = 0 To .Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
                Sheets(1).Cells(x + 1, y + 1).Value = .Rows(x).Cells(y).innertext
            Next y
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementByID` method takes a unique ID as an argument and returns a single HTML element if there is one with such an ID value.

Probably what you need to do is use the `getElementsByTagName` method, which returns a collection of matching elements. Since this may result in multiple matches, I find it best to create an object first, and an iterator variable:

```
Dim compresults
Dim el

Set compresults = htm.getelementsbytagname("comps-results")
For each el in compresults
    MsgBox el.InnerText

Next
```

BTW, I am fairly certain ( but have not verified) that an HTMLElementCollection does **not** have a `.Rows` member, so the next line in your code will probably raise an error.  Likewise, the `.Rows` does **not** have a `.Length` property, so there's at least two errors on that single line of code **AND** in the next line, note that `.Cells` does **not** have a `.Length` member, either, so another error.

For assistance with those parts of your code, I urge you to ask a new question.  This answer addresses your original question.

Comment: Hi David,

Thank so much for fast answer.
This code was posted in here by someone else and it works fine with this website, but does not work when I try to change the web site address. As I am a novice in vba, I don't know how he got the "Comps-results" from within the website.

Comment: If you don't even know what you're looking for, how is anyone supposed to assist you?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to get a specific data from a website using VBA, for example https://www.google.com/finance. I only want to read the data for Hang seng index and Nikkie 225 from this website. How can I do this?

Comment: The first step would be to not send your XMLHTTPRequest to Zillow.com. Then ymanually identify the ID or Classname of the element(s) you wish to obtain from the site's source XML. Then use an XML library like MSXML2 to parse the `.responseText` for those element(s). It is not terribly difficult but assumes basic understanding of VBA and XML in general.  I'm sorry but I'm not going to teach you how to do either of these. SO is for *specific questions* implementing code, not a general "Teach me everything I need to do in order to solve my very specific job".